# Scrolling form in android does not work when keyboard is on

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a registration form that contains several TextEdits and TextViews for showing errors. the problem is when the keyboard is on, the user can not scroll down to the the bottom elements although this property is set for the activity in the manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"




 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <com.nvanbenschoten.motion.ParallaxImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/dark"
         />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/trending_gradient_shape" />
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/color_white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@null"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarThemeWhite"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>


        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivUserPhoto"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_between_fields"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_user"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:civ_border_color="@android:color/white"
            app:civ_border_width="4dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:textColorHint="@color/color_white"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/normal_rounded_text_field"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="First Name"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/form_field_text_size"
            android:id="@+id/first_name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/family_name"
            android:nextFocusForward="@+id/family_name"
                />
            <TextView
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/error_first_name"
                android:textColor="@color/color_red_700"
                android:text="error"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/form_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/form_margin"
                android:layout_height="20dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_between_fields"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:textColorHint="@color/color_white"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/normal_rounded_text_field"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Family Name"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/form_field_text_size"
            android:id="@+id/family_name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/first_name"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/email"
            android:nextFocusForward="@+id/email"
            />
        <TextView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/error_family_name"
            android:textColor="@color/color_red_700"
            android:text="error"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_between_fields"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </LinearLayout>







    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/form_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/form_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_between_fields"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.foxtrapp.mysmallcommunity.ui.OnItemNotSelectedSpinner
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/normal_rounded_text_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/gender"
            android:popupBackground="@null"
            android:entries="@array/gender"/>
        <TextView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/error_gender"
            android:textColor="@color/color_red_700"
            android:text="error"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>


        <EditText
            android:textColorHint="@color/color_white"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/normal_rounded_text_field"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/family_name"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/form_field_text_size"
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/password"
            android:nextFocusForward="@+id/password"
            />
        <TextView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/error_email"
            android:textColor="@color/color_red_700"
            android:text="error"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_between_fields"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </LinearLayout>







        <EditText
            android:textColorHint="@color/color_white"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/normal_rounded_text_field"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/form_field_text_size"
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/email"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/confirm_password"
            android:nextFocusForward="@+id/confirm_password"
            />
        <TextView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/error_password"
            android:textColor="@color/color_red_700"
            android:text="error"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_between_fields"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </LinearLayout>



        <EditText
            android:textColorHint="@color/color_white"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/normal_rounded_text_field"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:hint="Confirm Password"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/form_field_text_size"
            android:id="@+id/confirm_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/password"
            />
        <TextView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/error_confirm_password"
            android:textColor="@color/color_red_700"
            android:text="error"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_between_fields"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </LinearLayout>


        <Button
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_get_st"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/form_margin"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="@dimen/form_field_text_size"
            android:id="@+id/confirm"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Note: when I add just textEdit without any additional parts the scrolling works perfectly,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer; I think somehow there is a contradiction between the full screen mode and scrolling in the form. I had to remove using full screen code in order to solve the problem i.e. I removed the following code from my activity

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try 

<RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView>
<RelativeLayout>
--------------------
Your EditText and other widget
-------------------
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the same, no difference